# zip many files with Air as3 flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, zip

OK . I am reasonably capable, but still learning.
This is for a program I am writing in AIR.
Basicaly I am needing to grab the files of mixed type and content from a given folder and zip them.

Here is the code I have put together and it sort of works.
Problem I have is that the files in the zip all have zero byte's in them. Efectivly empty.
What have I missed or done wrong?

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.events.Event;
import deng.fzip.*;

var directory:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("FOLDER/");

var zip:FZip = new FZip(); 
var files:Array = directory.getDirectoryListing();
for(var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    zip.addFile(files[i].name, files[i].data);
    trace(files[i].name);
}

var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
zip.serialize(ba); 
ba.position = 0; 
var finalZIP:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("TEST.zip"); 
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
fs.open(finalZIP, FileMode.WRITE); 
fs.writeBytes(ba); 
fs.close();
```

EDIT=:
While running the code, I have noticed this in the errors panel.

```
  ....app\scripts_classes\deng\fzip\FZipFile.as, Line 362   Warning: 1106: Empty statement found where block of code expected. Did you type ';'     accidentally?
```

and it seems to be fine from what I can see, but then I did not write the Fzip script.

Comment: I think that it is something to do with how I am trying to do it. By that, I mean that I am trying to have it automated.    

This link is the closesed I have found, but it relies on the user to select items and location as well as the name of zip file....
 === http://pradeek.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/nochump === 

I have tried to monify it to be automatic, but that is when the problems start.

Can anyone give an idea on how please.

Answer (score 0):

[`File.data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data) is only populated after a call to `File.load`.

For synchronous loading of bytes, look at `FileStream`.  [These docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc2.html) give a rundown.

Comment: I cant seem to get it. I have looked at all the gumpf and cant see it. Not sure if it is because of the way I am trying to call the files or if I am just missing something. I still cant get any "Data" to come in. I can read everything else..... Also get the odd "Array -V- File" conflict?